# At least one match

Tags: regex

I would like to detect titles with the name:

```
S1 Ep24 ...
S11 ...
Ep2 ...
```

The regex I have now is:

```
^(S[0-9]+ )?(Ep[0-9])?.+$
```

But both of these are optional. Is there a simple way to ensure one or both of the groups are matched? Or do I need to actually do something like: term1|term2|term1&term2 ? I'm hoping there is a less-verbose way that I'm missing. Currently I have:

```
^((S[0-9]+ Ep[0-9])|(S[0-9]+)|(Ep[0-9]+)).+$
```

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "One or both"? "One or the other" sounds like simple XOR, `(S[0-9]+|Ep[0-9]+)`

Comment: @wjandrea yes exactly, it should be more like "at least one" but could be S1 EP2

Comment: I guess you're looking for `^(?:S\d+(?:\s*Ep\d+)?|Ep\d+).+$`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wEPq6M/1

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yea, want to put that into an answer with a bit of detail then and I can accept it?

Comment: @David542 Done. Please let me know if there's anything that's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture the individual parts (season & episode) of the string, you may use the following:

```
^(?:(S\d+)(\s*Ep\d+)?|Ep\d+).+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q3ERmp/1/)**.

In this case, group #1 will contain the season (if it exists) and group #2 will contain the episode (if it exists).

If you don't care about the individual parts, the above pattern would be:

```
^(?:S\d+(?:\s*Ep\d+)?|Ep\d+).+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wEPq6M/1)**.

However, in this case, there will be no need to overcomplicate things because simply using `^(?:S\d+|Ep\d+).+$` would match the same.

Note that `\d` will match any digit just like `[0-9]` but the difference is that `\d` will also match any Unicode-defined digits. Which one you decide to use is entirely up to you based on your actual requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookbehind to ensure that at least one of them is matched: `(?<=.)`

This only works where you're matching from the start (`^`).

```
^(S[0-9]+)?(Ep[0-9])?(?<=.).+$
```

Matches:

```
S1 Ep24 ...
S11 ...
Ep2 ...
```

Doesn't match:

```
foobar ...
```

[Try it on Regexr](https://regexr.com/54sc4)

Comment: P.s. if you want to extract bits, it gets more complicated

Comment: Looks good but careful with lookbehind. It has very limited support on browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: @adel Good point. OP didn't mention language or flavour so I just assumed PCRE.

Comment: @wjandrea yea that's a great idea. I'm using Mysql though and the regexp is pretty limited (thus my `[0-9]` instead of `\d`) but this is really a great solution, thank you!